# WPF LiveCharts Line Series visibility bugged

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

Before I ask my question, here is what I'm doing:

VS 2015, WPF Live Charts -

4 line series in one CartesianChart.Series, all with binded visibility.

Basically my code works perfectly, the only problem is this:
When I toggle the visibility of a line series on and off, there is a remaining unwanted line. The images below will make it clearer (some components are hidden, only showing 2 line series).

First picture is initial display, then I check 'Food Panda Sales' and uncheck 'Net Shop Sales'. The bindings are all correctly coded.

[image]

[image]

My question: **How do I get rid of that blue triangular area thing that remains even after the series visibility is turned to hidden/collapsed? Note that re-checking the boxes brings back the line series correctly with the triangle gone.**

Comment: This is a bug you are right, moved it to https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/issues/328 so we can fix it better

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to find a workaround till then :)